# Angular, http interceptor content type: application/json

Tags: angularjs, http, content-type, interceptor

Here's my angular interceptor:

```
.service('TestInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', '$log', 
function ($q, $rootScope, $log) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        request: function (config) {
            console.log("request");
            return config;
        },
        requestError: function (rejection) {
            console.log("requestError");
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },
        response: function (response) {
            console.log("response");
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            console.log("responseError");
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Now it only displays logs in console, I'm testing Angular interceptors. It works fine with `Content-Type:text/html` but problem is that it doesn't work with `Content-Type:application/json`, there's no logs after that type of request, response.
Any ideas why? Maybe I should config something?

EDIT:
Here I'm adding my interceptor:

```
angular.module('test-module').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TestInterceptor');
}]);
```

Comment: Can you post where you've added TestInterceptor to interceptors array? Something like this - $httpProvider.interceptors.push

Comment: @SidharthPanwar added in question